# Include UI interactivity inside Server Component in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Considering the following Server Component inside the new app/ directory in NextJS:

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const categories = await getCategories();

  // const [navigation, setNavigation] = React.useState('hidden');

  function handleHover() {
     // hide or show the navigation bar without losing server side rendering
}

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={poppins.className}>
        <header className={"fixed left-0 top-0 w-full"}>
          <div
            className={
              "flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-4 p-6 shadow"
            }
          >
            <div
              className={
                "flex flex-row items-center justify-center space-x-5 font-extralight"
              }
            >
              {categories.map((data) => (
                <Link onMouseEnter={handleHover} href={"/new"} className={"link uppercase"}>
                  {data}
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${navigation} nav-bar z-10 min-h-[250px] w-full justify-center p-6 shadow`}
          ></div>
        </header>

        <div className={"mx-auto 2xl:container"}>{children}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I need to show the nav-bar div when the mouse hovers over a category.
This would work when using "use client", however I don't want to lose Server Side Rendering.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it. you need user interactivity and in server components, you cannot have user interactivity because you are on the server not on the browser environment.

When you hover the mouse on the element, the `mouseover` event gets triggered by the browser and action gets executed by the javascript engine.

server components are helpful for computation-heavy tasks because you can scale up your server to send the response quicker. Or they are helpful for SEO purposes. So if you render the navbar on client you are not going to lose too much.

Comment: So if I want to create a list of articles (components with thumbnail, title, description) and a search field to sort them by, say, title, am I screwed then? I definitely want the list of articles to render server-side, otherwise the website if screwed on the SEO part, but I need interactivity within it, like receiving props from a HOC that define a filtering rule.

Comment: @Telion exaclty my problem. I guess Next.js is dead for website development.

Comment: @MarekMaurizio Client-side components in Next.js are still pre-rendered server side, but their interactivity (JS) code is executed in the browser after the HTML has been sent to the browser, along with a JS payload that "hydrates" the react components back to an interactive state. You need to make sure the data the components need to render is fetched server-side and given to your client-side component, not fetched inside a useEffect or other client-side event though. The client component cannot pre-render data it doesn't have!

Comment: You can prove that a client-component gets pre-rendered by disabling JavaScript in your browser and then refreshing your site. If the component is rendered with the data you expected, you are rendering it correctly server-side. You can add a JS disable button in Chrome toolbar with this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-javascript/jfpdlihdedhlmhlbgooailmfhahieoem

Comment: Thank you, my bad I did not understand that client side is still pre-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you put your navbar in a separate component/file, like navbar.jsx. You put 'use client' there, and just use the component  in your layout.jsx.